# Protractor cannot locate a element/value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Below is the html code:

```
<tab id="briefcase" ng-controller="BriefcaseController as vm" active="main.uiState.briefcaseOpen">
        <tab-heading>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i><br>
            My Court Cases <span id="briefcaseCount" ng-show="main.briefcase.contents.length" class="badge">{{main.briefcase.contents.length}}</span>
        </tab-heading>
        <ng-include src="'app/components/briefcase/briefcase.html'"></ng-include>
    </tab>
```

I followed the example given in protractor API:
view:

```
<span id="foo">{{variableInScope}}</span>
```

code:

```
var value = element(by.id('foo')).evaluate('variableInScope');
```

in my case since I have 2 instances with same expression, I did the following:

```
var value = element.all(by.id('briefcaseCount')).get(0).evaluate('main.briefcase.contents.length');
```

When I call `console.log(value)`.. I am getting [object, Object]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *resolve the promise* to see the real value on the console:

```
element.all(by.id('briefcaseCount')).first().evaluate('main.briefcase.contents.length').then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

If you just need to assert value, pass it to `expect()` - it would *implicitly resolve the promise*:

```
var value = element.all(by.id('briefcaseCount')).first().evaluate('main.briefcase.contents.length');
expect(value).toEqual("somevalue");
```